# capsule collider not jumping in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

i imported a the `Unity chan` character from unity assets store , when i and i added to it `rigidbody` and `capsuleCollider` ,and then i assigned to it the

JUMP00 animation as in the images , so when i hit play the character jumps but the collider is not moving up , when i add motion to move x and z axis the collider moves with the character.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is by design. Animation only move the mesh, it does nothing to `collider`.

One workaround to this problem is that you can attach your collider to the bone not the mesh.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved my problem which has the same behavior. The cause of my problem was because I did not move the GameObject (up), I just was playing the animation, not make a really jumping for the object.

I know this old post, but I answered for the newer game programmer like me :)